# Get the last timestamp of a month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e145579cb7abc8b8627e9b18a8e9218)**

```
CREATE TABLE PaL (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO PaL
(event_date)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01'),
('2020-02-05'),
('2020-03-20'),
('2020-04-15'),
('2020-05-11'),
('2020-06-18'),
('2020-07-19'),
('2020-12-31');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
event_date            |   last_timestamp_of_the_month        |
----------------------|---------------------------------- ---|-----------
2020-01-02            |       2020-01-31 23:59:59            |    
2020-02-05            |       2020-02-29 23:59:59            |   
2020-03-20            |       2020-03-31 23:59:59            |    
2020-04-15            |       2020-04-30 23:59:59            |
2020-05-11            |       2020-05-31 23:59:59            |    
2020-06-18            |       2020-06-30 23:59:59            |  
2020-07-19            |       2020-07-31 23:59:59            | 
2021-12-31            |       2020-12-31 23:59:59            |
```

---

In the results I want to get the last timestamp of each month of the event_date. 
Therefore I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, +1, date_trunc('month', pl.event_date)))::timestamp AS last_timestamp_of_the_month
FROM PaL pl
```

The query already gives me the last day of the month. 
However, instead of `23:59:59` it assigns `00:00:00` to it.

How do I need to change the query to get the `23:59:59` behind each date as in the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't access to any redshift platform can't say for sure but below query should work. Please try this. Instead of subtracting a day subtract a second.

```
SELECT 
DATEADD(sec, -1, DATEADD(month, +1, date_trunc('month', pl.event_date)))::timestamp AS last_timestamp_of_the_month
FROM PaL pl
```

Comment: @Michi Please let me know your feed-back.