# CONCAT function in amazon-redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So far I have used the following `CONCAT` function:

```
CONCAT('SQL', ' is', ' fun')
```

However, in redshift I get the error:

```
ERROR: function concat("unknown", "unknown", "unknown") does not exist
```

Is there any other function that I could use to replace the `CONCAT` and get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RedShift you can concatenate two string with concat(). Try this:

```
CONCAT('SQL', CONCAT(' is', ' fun'))
```

Or you can use (||) instead like below:

```
'SQL' || ' is' || ' fun'
```

Comment: Any idea for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634151/get-the-last-timestamp-of-a-month as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the number of parameters.
The function accepts two and you are passing three.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CONCAT.html